# Estou fazendo um programa em python, e o return não está funcionando

Tags: python, return

```
def primo(b, d):
    d = 0
    c = 1
    x = 0
    while c < b+1:
        if b % c == 0:
            x += 1
        c +=1
    if x == 2:
        d = 1
    return d

d = 0
c = []
b = 3
a = int(input ("coloque o número que você quer que seja 'fatorado': "))
while a > 1:
    d = 0
    if a % 2 == 0:
        a = a / 2
        int(a)
        c.append("2x")
        print (a)
    else:
        primo(b, d)
        if d == 1:
            print (d)
            c.append(b, "x")
            a = a /b
            b = 3
        else:
            b +=1

print (c)
```

Comment: `primo(b, d)` não deveria ser atribuido a alguma variável?

Answer (score 1):

Seu método `primo(b, d)` retorna o valor "d", porém quando você chama o método ele não está armazenando este retorno em nenhum lugar. Para solucionar este problema, atribua a função a uma variável, por exemplo:

```
variavel_retorno = primo(b, d)
```

Se quiseres descobrir se o método está funcionando coloca um `print(variavel_retorno)` logo após chamar o método.